# how to get diffrence between two dates using DATEDIFF function dynamically using sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

here is my table namely book_master having following detail

```
id     book_nmae      book_cost   publish_date
6   maths         150.0000     1992-08-06
7   science       120.0000     1992-08-07
8   gujrati       100.0000     1992-08-08
9   english       105.0000     1992-08-09
10  social study  100.0000     1992-08-10
```

here i want to get diffrence between publish_date 1992-08-06 and  1992-08-07  using book_name column.

i have tried below conditions to sql

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,book_master.publish_date,book_master.publish_date) 
from book_master where  book_name in('science','maths')

select DATEDIFF(DAY,book_master.publish_date.book_name('maths'),book_master.publish_date.book_name('science')) 
from book_master
```

regards
rajdeep parmar

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Date1 AS DATETIME
DECLARE @Date2 AS DATETIME

SELECT @Date1 = publish_date 
FROM book_master
WHERE book_name = 'science'

SELECT @Date2 = publish_date 
FROM book_master
WHERE book_name = 'maths'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@Date1,@Date2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,T1.publish_date,T2.publish_date)
FROM
  (
    SELECT publish_date
    FROM book_master
    WHERE book_name = 'science'
  ) T1
CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT publish_date
    FROM book_master
    WHERE book_name = 'maths'
  ) T2
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching books by name I would use the `id` assuming that those `id`'s are unique.
Solution:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, -- this PK constraint ensures unique values for this column
    book_name NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    publish_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT  @MyTable(id,book_name,publish_date)
VALUES  
(6 ,'maths       ', '1992-08-06'),
(7 ,'science     ', '1992-08-07'),
(8 ,'gujrati     ', '1992-08-08'),
(9 ,'english     ', '1992-08-09'),
(10,'social study', '1992-08-10');

DECLARE @book_id_1 INT,
        @book_id_2 INT;
SELECT  @book_id_1=6,
        @book_id_2=7;       

SELECT  DATEDIFF(DAY,pvt.[1],pvt.[2]) AS DaysDiff
FROM(       
    SELECT  t.publish_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.publish_date) AS RowNum
    FROM    @MyTable t
    WHERE   t.id IN (@book_id_1,@book_id_2)
) x
PIVOT(MAX(x.publish_date) FOR x.RowNum IN ([1],[2])) pvt;
```

Result:

```
DaysDiff
-----------
1
```